# How to use Drupal as static website generator?

Tags: 8

When I want to convert my Drupal 7 site to html files I have used [Static module](https://www.drupal.org/project/static), which converts Drupal 7 site to html files. However, I will like to know how I can convert a Drupal 8 into static html pages.

Any ideas on how I can make a Drupal 8 website into static html pages ?

Comment: Convert the module yourself.

Comment: Gatsby is a "Blazing-fast static site generator for React", it has a D8 plugin. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-drupal/

(I think this is a good question.)

Comment: There is Drupal 8 static generator - https://www.drupal.org/project/tome.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there are any plans for the [static project](https://www.drupal.org/project/static) to be ported to Drupal 8.

However, a workaround to turn your Drupal 8 into a static site is by using the `wget --mirror` command. This will take an exact copy your site.